# Using View Pager Adapter's Position to Change a Global Variable

Tags: android, android-viewpager, global-variables

I am attempting to change a global variable using the page position of a view pager.

Inside my view pager adapter:

```
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    ...

    Global global = new Global();
    switch(position){
        case 0: global.setLocation("0");
            break;
        case 1: global.setLocation("1");
            break;
        case 2: global.setLocation("2");
            break;
        case 3: global.setLocation("3");
            break;
        default: global.setLocation("");
            break;
    }
    return item_view;
}
```

If I switch pages, so does the location... However, when I toast the location, it is the incorrect location.

Example: I'm on page 3, global.getLocation = "2" or I'm on page 1, global.getLocation = "3"; (Answers appear to vary randomly)

**What is incorrect about using the position of a view pager to change a global variable?**

**How can I accomplish this task correctly?**

More code for attempted solution...

```
public class Location extends AppCompatActivity {
  ViewPager viewPager;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location2);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
    adapterLocation = new CustomSwipeAdapterLocation(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterLocation);

    int position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    Toast.makeText(this, position,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    ...
```

Error:

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: andrewnguyen.finishedmoietyapp, PID: 5463
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{andrewnguyen.finishedmoietyapp/andrewnguyen.finishedmoietyapp.Location}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

The error refers to line "**int position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) and getting the position inside `onPageSelected()` method:

```
   viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Global global = new Global();
            switch(position){
                case 0: global.setLocation("0");
                    break;
                case 1: global.setLocation("1");
                    break;
                case 2: global.setLocation("2");
                    break;
                case 3: global.setLocation("3");
                    break;
                default: global.setLocation("");
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

---

Another option use [getCurrentItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem()) to get the real item position:

```
viewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

if you use the `position` variable of  `instantiateItem()` the position values are changing when new pages are instantiated

Comment: This is what I tried...                                                                                       int position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        Toast.makeText(this, position,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: very strange to have "String resource ID #0x0", anyway i have added another method, see my answer.

Comment: Glad to help you! have a nice day!